# Jenkins MultiJob - Send Results e-mail with data from inner Jobs

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have a MultiJob Project with 3 inner jobs which needs to be executed in the following sequence

```
Master MultiJob Project (Job)
 |----- Phase 1
            |------> JOB A 
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB B
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB C
```

When Job C ends, the Master MultiJob Project (Job) will send a mail (Using the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)) with status about the results from all the inner Jobs (A, B and C) (As a Post Build Step)

I need to find a way to get a the results from each of these inner Jobs (as Parameter or any other way...)

I tried to do it by:

1. Setting Enviroment Variable and then trying to read it - Failed - the Varaiable is not exisintg anymore after Job A/B/C ends
2. Tried to do so with SETX, same results
3. Tried to use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and failed again

isn't there anyway to do so?

Can someone shade some light?

Comment: What kind of information would you need from the those jobs (A/B/C)?

Comment: @vik I want to take the results from each inner job and also to take build number of this inner job

Comment: Multijob plugin does not let you pass results/build# as parameters. So the only possible solution I can think of is to use the [Groovy PostBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) and grab the results from each job using a groovy script. We do that samething to get SVN revision number of another job in the same Multijob Suite.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your job is a Multijob, you can add a groovy post build like this:

```
subBuilds = manager.build.getSubBuilds()
//print the each sub build instance to the console log and its result
subBuilds.each{
    manager.listener.logger.println "${it}, ${it.getResult()}"
}
```