# Is there a way in Jenkins to iterate over the build steps and extract the results?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that I use to execute tests, and I would like to compile+send a nice-looking report. Each set of tests is executed by a "MultiJob Phase" step that references another job and passes in the specific parameters - there are several of these steps and more will be added in the future. I'm using the "Editable Email Notification" plugin to send my notification. So I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate over my build steps, extract step names and results of those steps, so that I can present that information in my notification? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Only way that I can think of is using parameters and passing the parameters across all the builds

Comment: please check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34897032/947784 it might be similar to what you are looking for.